# Recommendations for a heap analysis tool for Java?

Tags: java, memory, profiling, heap-memory

List your favorite heap analysis tools (e.g. jprofiler, jmap, ...).
Let's keep it one tool per answer, with a short list of pros and cons for each tool.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

**YourKit** : http://www.yourkit.com/

**Pros:**

- The interface is clean and it's fast
- It opened a large 5-gig heap dump where jProfiler grined to a halt. And it only needed 1-2 gigs of JVM ram to do so.

**Cons:**
Of course... it's not free :(

Comment: Well, just note that when trying to open a 20GB heap with YourKit it crashed on OOME, so YourKit won't help you by allowing you have open a large heap with a commodity Macbook Pro

Answer (score 59):

Eclipse Memory analyzer http://www.eclipse.org/mat/

- Support for multiple JVMs
- Help with identifying sources for memory leaks
  (see http://www.sdn.sap.com/irj/scn/weblogs?blog=/pub/wlg/6856)
- Open source and actively developed by major vendors (SAP and IBM)
- Part of Galileo release of Eclipse

Comment: I know this is from '10, but anyone know what the tool to identify Memory Leaks was pointing to and what replaced it if anything?

Comment: @GREnvoy the tool is called sap jvm profiler  and you should be able to find some resources on google. Not sure if it's been replaced by a different tool

Comment: is there a command line tools to detect if memory leak in the heap dump file?

Answer (score 36):

Consider Java VisualVM, [`jvisualvm`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/share/jvisualvm.html), included with the JDK. A pathologic Swing program is examined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6309407/230513). For a more recent perspective, see the [*Monitoring and Management Guide: Using JConsole*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/management/overview-java-se-monitoring-and-management.html) regarding [`jconsole`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/management/using-jconsole.html#GUID-77416B38-7F15-4E35-B3D1-34BFD88350B5), also included with the JDK.

Comment: On Mac OS X, see [*Where did jvisualvm go?*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13312229/230513)

Answer (score 5):

BHeapSampler http://dr-brenschede.de/bheapsampler/

- generates a class-level heap-graph as a really intuitive display of the dominant memory structures
- can process really large heap dumps
- command-line tool, usable on server side without transfering the dump to the developer's desk

Comment: Closed source code and throws an strange exception with a.a() obfuscation. Looks like this tool is not working.